# Is there a name for incompletely-sliced potatoes?

Tags: potatoes, cutting

I recently made [this recipe](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ina-garten/rosemary-roasted-potatoes-recipe2-2012807), but I am wondering if there are any names for this type of slicing (for potatoes, and otherwise).  I suppose it somewhat resembles "blooming" an onion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Potatoes that have been sliced *almost* all the way, buttered, spiced and then roasted until they fan out often go by the name [Hasselback Potatoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasselbackspotatis).

Reputedly they were invented by a Swedish chef in the 1950s and the name is based on the name of the Swedish restaurant, Hasselbacken, in Stockholm.

I don't think there is a specific culinary term for "slicing almost all the way".

Answer (score 1):

This method is commonly known as "hasselback".